# Import rpyc not working in azure web service python flask application

Tags: python, azure, rpyc

1)Import rpyc not working in azure web service python flask application, Its shows 
 "**[image: Application Error If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources]**."

2)How to insall rpyc in azure app service with flask application?

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something what you can do:

- Create requirement.txt file with all your dependent libraries, simple declaration would be in your txt file like below:

```js
    beautifulsoup4  ==4.8.1
    bs4             ==0.0.1
    Click           ==7.0
    cycler          ==0.10.0
    django-cors     ==0.1
    Flask           ==1.1.1
```

- Create .venv file under your root folder with below values:

```js
    FLASK_APP=StartupFile.py
    FLASK_ENV=development
```

- Once you deployed the solution , open the KUDU app of your azure portal:

[image]

- You can open the BASH and browse the directory which would be wwwroot:

[image]

- Execute the command in below order:

```js
   python3 -m venv venv
    source venv/bin/activate
    pip install -r requirements.txt
    export FLASK_APP=application.py
    flask run
```

Similarly your module will be installed in the virtual environment. Add the dependency in your requirement.txt.

Additional reference:

https://jackstromberg.com/2018/07/installing-python-wheel-files-on-an-azure-app-service/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Mohit Verma, Its working fine. I want to run rpyc_classic.py 
In bash file, After running,  its shows the error  "no module named rpyc". So I tried to pip install rpyc.. Its keep on asking Cleaning up.... Pls help.

Comment: refresh your Bash command window , browse through wwwroot  and  try installing the file using wheel file like : pip install --use-wheel pillow and  pip install (file name).whl , should be installed then

Comment: For installing wheel library , you have to run first pip install wheel and then you can execute pip install (file name).whl

Comment: Hi Mohit, After pip install wheel getting below exception.. ..
no such option: --use-wheel Usage:  
  pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...
no such option: --use-wheel

Comment: Check this link for installing libraries in Azure linux. It will guide you to install libraries using wheel

Comment: Alternatively after activating venv try executing pip wheel -r requirements.txt -w wheelhouse. It works

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me in which link to proceed to install wheel libraries?

Comment: https://jackstromberg.com/2018/07/installing-python-wheel-files-on-an-azure-app-service/

Comment: Please mark it as answer as it will help other who have the same ask.

Comment: sorry Mohit.., still facing no such option exception, while pip install wheel.